# Java: why static field are "independent" each other?

Tags: java, static, field

In the following code the `set` method changes the field values of `Calendar` class.
The field `YEAR` is declared `static int YEAR`. So why by creating two objects of `Calendar` class, the changes to one object will reflect to the other? Here this doesn't happen.
I would ask you how Java developers have implemented this?

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2011,9,13);
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Calendar.YEAR` is a constant that is only used to *name* a field used by the `Calendar`. The *value* of that field is **not** static: it can and will vary between instances of `Calendar`.

`Calendar` defines a number of these field names for the different components of date and time, specifically to be used with get and set operations for the corresponding fields.

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#YEAR) the section in the javadoc for `Calendar.YEAR`.

As for the implementation, the `set` and `get` methods are aware of these different field types, and change values in the instance based on the constant passed in. Think of it like a big `switch` statement in `get` or `set`, switching on all the field values.

Comment: so, how it's declared? static int YEAR ..?

Comment: `public static final int YEAR_FIELD`

Comment: i saw, but how it's done (at code level) the link between the static Calendar field YEAR and the internal field of each object?

Comment: @sleax in this case, the `Calendar.get` method is written so that it understands the usage of the different constants. So when you call `Calendar.get`, it looks at the constant passed, for instance, `YEAR`, and returns the corresponding value. So in the `get` method, there's something like a big `switch` statement with all of the possible constant field names. Same with the `Calendar.set` method

Answer (score 3):

`YEAR` (and other related fields) are just constants that are used to tell your `Calendar` which field you want. If you look at the value of `YEAR`, you'll see it's actually `static final` [with a value of 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.YEAR).

The year for an individual `Calendar` is ultimately stored in the `Calendar` objects, as you would expect, and the `YEAR` constant is used only to ask the `Calendar` for its actual year value.